# How to filter two lists and make a new list

Tags: list, groovy

If I have two String lists like below and want to make a new String list based on `startsWith` logic, how can I do it?

```
pathList = ["/etc/passwd/something.txt",
            "/etc/fonts/fonts.conf" 
            "/var/www/foo.bar", 
            "/some/foo/path/one.txt"]
notAllowedPathList = ["/etc/fonts",  
                      "/var", 
                      "/path"]

newList = ["/etc/passwd/something.txt", "/some/foo/path/one.txt"]
```

`newList` is created by seeing whether each element in `pathList` `startsWith` each element in `newList`.

So, from the above `pathList`, `/etc/fonts/fonts.conf` and `/var/www/foo.bar` are removed because they startWith `/etc/fonts` and `/var` respectively.

I came up with below but I believe there would be a more groovy way of doing this:

```
    def newList = []
    pathList.each {String fileName ->
        notAllowedPathList.find { String notAllowed ->
            if (fileName.startsWith(notAllowed)) {
                return true
            }
            else {
                newList << fileName
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def pathList = [
    "/etc/passwd/something.txt",
    "/etc/fonts/fonts.conf", 
    "/var/www/foo.bar", 
    "/some/foo/path/one.txt"
]

def notAllowedPathList = ["/etc/fonts", "/var", "/path"]

def newList = pathList.findAll { String fileName ->
    !notAllowedPathList.any { 
        fileName.startsWith(it)
    }
}
```

Comment: wow I didn't know `!` can be prepended to `any`. Can you please explain what it does?

Comment: `any` returns true if any element of the collection it's invoked upon returns a truthy value when passed to the closure argument